# Why does my system not allow me to snap file windows to either side of the screen?

Tags: gui

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon.

By 'snap' I mean that feature which allows one to partition the window to either side of the screen either by dragging the window to a side or through some keyboard short-cut (ordinarily super+left-arrow)

By 'file windows' I mean those windows which display the content of directories via the GUI not the terminal.

Sorry for the lengthy explanations, but I don't know the proper terms and just want to make myself clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not already installed you should install `Extension Manager` and select the extension `Arrange Windows`

[image]

If not installed you can do so with the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

There are other extensions such as `Awesome Tiles` and others you can experiment with to find the ones that suit you best.

This one may be worth exploring too (indeed the one the OP agrees works for him):

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly, but this did not fix the issue.

Comment: another one *Tiling Assistant* for you try using `Extension Manager` is shown in my answer which may work for you.

Comment: Wow. That actually works out of the box. Needs a little configuring, though. Thank you!

Comment: perhaps then mark the answer as accepted (grey tick) and give it an upvote so that others with the same issue can easily find it. Thanks